# Getting Properties of Next Record Using Calculate Field Tool in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to calculate the distance between the centroids of adjacent records (adjacent in the attribute table, not necessarily in space) into an attribute field. I'm planning on using the truecentroid.x and truecentroid.y properties of one record and the next record in the attribute table with the Pythagorean theorem to calculate distance. but can't figure a way to get to the properties of the next record. I'm not a great programmer but I can usually hack something together.

Can someone suggest a starting point for me?

Comment: Populate additional field by oid-1 and join to itself

Comment: Perfect! That was the solution. I'd completely forgotten to follow the KISS principal. Keep It Simple Stupid.

Comment: Might not work on database fc if oid is not sequential

Comment: @FelixIP Looks like you have almost two sentences and an answer in your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Populate additional field by OID - 1 and join to itself.

Please note that solution will always work for shapefiles (FID), but might fail for database feature class if OBJECTIDs are not sequential numbers